# Joomla ZOO item counter

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0, zoo

I'm using joomla 3, zoo component.

In the backend of the system i have this code to display numbers of items in the every zoo application installed:

```
<?php echo $application->getItemCount(); ?>
```

What i need is to edit this code to display only numbers of items that are "published".

I'm not sure how to do this as i'm not a php coder.
Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

You could try fetching the data from the database. Check out the doc [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase). Here is some sample code witch should help

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('COUNT(*)');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__tablename'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('published') . ' = 1');
$row = $db->loadRow();
print_r($row);
```

You will need to find the table where the data is stored and replace __tablename accordingly (and maybe change the column name "published" if needed)

Comment: i look at the doc and try 2 variations now.. both of them give me the numbers of all rows and dont take if its published.. (published is state in the table and values are 0 and 1) `$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('COUNT(*)');
$query->from($db->quoteName('a9qiy_zoo_item'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('state')." = ".$db->quote(['1']));
 
// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);
$count = $db->loadResult(); ?>`